# On an assumption that $a+b+c+d=0$ in a proof with complex numbers of geomtrical problem

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Inside T. Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis* book, p. 16, he declares $a+b+c+d=0$, as the quadrilateral is close up. Somewhat I am not convinced. Please help me understand what he really means for this equality, and why it is true in this case. I am attaching a screenshot of this page as well.

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: Think of the complex numbers $a,b,c,d$ as vectors in a two dimensional space. If you add vectors, you can geometrically interpret their sum as sticking them together, connecting the terminal point of one vector with the initial point of the next vector ( https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/adding-and-subtracting-vectors ). So the vectors form a closed shape precisely if they sum to 0

Comment: "declares ... as the quadrilateral is close up." Those words don't make grammatical sense.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, can you suggest please a better wording?

Comment: Np, because I have no idea what it is meant to say. Do you mean "declared ... because the quadrilateral is closed?"

Comment: Yes, sir, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visualize a complex number $z = a + bi$ as a vector $\langle a, b \rangle$ in the plane. Addition of complex numbers corresponds to componentwise addition of vectors:
\begin{align*}
z_1 + z_2 = (a_1 + b_1i) + (a_2 + b_2i) 
&= (a_1 + a_2) + (b_1 + b_2)\,i \\
\longleftrightarrow\qquad 
\langle a_1, b_1 \rangle + \langle a_2, b_2 \rangle &= 
\langle a_1+a_2, b_1+b_2 \rangle, 
\end{align*}
which you can visualize by placing the tail of the second vector at the head of the first, and completing the third side of the triangle as the sum vector. This is often called the *Parallelogram Law* for vector addition because if you do it in the other order, you construct the other path around the parallelogram to the opposite vertex.

[image: Parallelogram Law for vector addition]

Now, adding multiple vectors can be visualized by forming a polygonal chain, attaching the tail of each vector to the head of the previous one. The sum is the vector connecting the starting point to the final head. If the the polygon (in your case, a quadrilateral) closes up, that means that the *net* displacement (the sum of the vectors) is zero.

Of course, we could have been talking about complex numbers in the complex plane all along!